# OnClick Image (Push down Effect)

Tags: javascript, push

Looking for some help a simple onclick effect, sadly my memory is the same as a Gold fish so i cannot remember what to search to get some help on this.

Here's an example http://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=
If you click the Logo it kinda moves down like a Push.

Just something like that
Would really appreciate some help thanks.

Comment: Have you already take a look with Firebug of Firefox, or the webconsoles in Chrome and/or Safari browser?

Comment: Yep, tried to recreate it.
Sadly no luck.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you should do this in CSS with the :active selector. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active)

If you really do want to use javascript you will have to bind on mousedown (to set the margin/position/class) and on mouseup (to set it back to original) and probably on mouseleave for good measure.